# Materialize closeModal not firing complete

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular, materialize

If i call `$("#modal").closeModal();` inside the modal, the `complete` method is not triggered. I open the modal with the following.

```
$("#modal").openModal({
    dismissible: false,
    complete: this.doSomething
});
```

Is there something i am doing wrong? Is there a way to trigger the modal to close inside the modal, so that the `complete` method is triggered? I need to wait for something to happen before the modal is closed.

Comment: How is this related to Angular2? If it actually is please add more context. Where and how are you using this in Angular2?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

**html file**

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!--following line has the icon to close the modal on your command-->

    <h4>Modal Header <i class = "material-icons right" id = "closeIcon">close</i></h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>

    <!--following button adds text to the <p> tag with id = "textBody" i.e. its doing something and the modal wont close until that is done-->

    <button class = "btn waves-effect waves-light" id = "doSomething">Press me and do something</button>


  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
<p id = "textBody">

</p>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
    dismissible: false,

    /*waiting for the user to click the button before closing*/
    complete: $('#doSomething').click(function(){        

                  $('#textBody').html('i got a Boo Boo');
                  $('#modal1').closeModal();                    

              })          

  });
  $("#closeIcon").click(function(){
    $('#modal1').closeModal();
  });



})
```

here is the link to check what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/4y6ptm8k/4/

Comment: Sorry to stir this back up, but is there a way to fire the complete event strictly by calling closeModal and not via user input at all? I have exhausted google and haven't found a solution.

Comment: @IRCraziestTaxi you want the events to happen inside `closeModal()` function?